# Active Directory Auto Logoff Timer

Tags: windows-8, active-directory, logoff

I'm experimenting with an Active Directory Domain at home (Win Server 2012 Domain Controller). After joining my Windows 8 Pro (x64) PC to my domain, I am getting automatically logged off after being idle for a certain period of time (~60 minutes). This didn't happen before joining the domain, and ceases when I leave the domain.

I would like to change the idle logoff timer. I've looked within my default GPO settings and didn't see anything in there.

Where should I go to change this?

Edit: I am using a local user account on the computer as well, not an AD user.

Comment: Wow, that is strange...

Comment: Do a gpresult to pull up all the policies that are applied.  Then double check those policies through GP Manager to start with.